# Buffer is not defined (react-native)

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, expo, buffer

I can't use buffer in react-native app (built with the expo tool).

I have a geography Point value in hex like this for example -> `0101000020E61000003868AF3E1E0A494046B3B27DC8F73640`
and im trying to decode it to longitude and latitude with the following code ->

```js
import WktParser from 'terraformer-wkt-parser';
import wkx from 'wkx';
import wellknown from 'wellknown';
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';

  const wkb = new Buffer.from(point, 'hex');
  const wkt = wkx.Geometry.parse(wkb).toWkt();
  const parsedPoint = WktParser.parse(wellknown.stringify(wkt));
  const longitude = parseFloat(parsedPoint.coordinates[0]);
  const latitude = parseFloat(parsedPoint.coordinates[1]);

  return [latitude, longitude];
```

but got an error with a buffer like this ->
`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Buffer`
In package.json I have ->

```
    "terraformer-wkt-parser": "^1.2.1",
    "util": "^0.12.5",
    "wellknown": "^0.5.0",
    "wkx": "^0.5.0"
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "expo": "~47.0.12",
```

Also, I was trying other libraries and had the same result.
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the buffer module in `Expo`, you must install it using the `expo install buffer` command.

However, since `Expo` does not support buffer modules by default, executing the `expo install buffer` command may result in errors such as "Package 'buffer' is not found in the current configured register".

In this case, you can use the `Buffer` API by installing the `react-native-crypto` package instead.

However, because the `react-native-crypto` is not supported by `Expo`, you may need to use bare workflow by ejecting `Expo`.

> EDIT

My answer is not about `buffer`, I write additional answers to @matek comment questions.

you can use `base64` encoding

- Exmaple

```js
import { encode, decode } from 'base-64';

// Encoding coordinate values
const lat = 37.7749;
const lng = -122.4194;
const encodedLatLng = encode(`${lat},${lng}`);

// Decode encoded coordinate values
const decodedLatLng = decode(encodedLatLng).split(',');
const decodedLat = parseFloat(decodedLatLng[0]);
const decodedLng = parseFloat(decodedLatLng[1]);
```

Comment: @Matek If my answer helped you with your question, please check your answer and vote.

Comment: So basically what will be the best solution to convert this 0101000020E61000003868AF3E1E0A494046B3B27DC8F73640 to longitude and latitude in react-native. I tried crypto and not working.

Comment: @Matek Watch my update answer

Comment: Also one important thing in the backend I added 
@Field(() => GraphQLJSON)